# Grunt - ignore hidden files?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

With recurse:

```
grunt.file.recurse('../products/', function callback(abspath, rootdir, subdir, filename) {
....
```

How can I get it so it ignores hidden files:

```
.DS_Store
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `filename` provided to your callback, and bail out if you don't like it:

```
function callback(abspath, rootdir, subdir, filename) {
  if (filename.startsWith('.')) return;
  // Do things
}
```